# Lixeira, Rascunho e Revisão pendente no wordpress, como funcionam?

Tags: php, wordpress

Boa tarde, gostaria de uma ajuda de vocês, preciso tirar um post do ar, mas gostaria de reativa-lo independente do tempo de transcorrer, se daqui um ano eu quiser publica-lo novamente como devo proceder, pois depois de um tempo todos os posts da lixeira começam a sumir, a única alternativa que encontrei na internet foi utilizar

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 365 );
```

mas depois de 365 o mesmo é excluído permanentemente? e posso utilizar um periodo tem longo assim, ou existe outra forma como deixar o post como rascunho?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

só de deixar o post em rascunho ele não será eliminado, essa linha:

```
define( 'EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS', 365 );
```

é sobre limpar os posts que já estão na lixeira, o rascunho não é considerado lixeira.
Vou deixar esse [link](https://codex.wordpress.org/Trash_status) da documentação sobre o assunto

Comment: Muito obrigado @Danilo D, li a documentação e não encontrei menção a utilizar valores maiores que 30 dias, acabei lendo também os status dos posts disponíveis para a publicação [https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Status], vou enviar os dados que pretendo salvar para o rascunho...

Answer (score 2):

Acredito que o `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS` seja somente para quando deleta, isto não afeta os "rascunhos", então bastaria remover da publicação, mas se eu estiver enganado acredito que basta apenas remover a ação [`wp_schedule_delete`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_scheduled_delete), assim:

```
function my_remove_schedule_delete() {
    remove_action( 'wp_scheduled_delete', 'wp_scheduled_delete' );
}

add_action( 'init', 'my_remove_schedule_delete' );
```

Comment: ainda sou muito novo em wordpress tenho um pouco de receio em alterar os arquivos, mas muito obrigado @GuilhermeNascimento

Comment: @WagnerFernandoMomesso realmente não tem haver com os rascunhos, o `EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS ` é somente para deletador permanentemente, então nem precisa mexer em nada :)